# Check EMA crossover on Daily TF

Tags: pine-script

I'm quite new to pine script and needed your help with some code. I've got 2 emas and i wanted sme help checking for a crossover on a daily tf without changing the timeframe. say im on the h1 and it alerts me when there;s a crossover on the daily tf

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `resolution` argument in `study` to `"D"`.

```
study("My Script",resolution="D")
```